# How to setup a BeginXXX EndXXX method call with moq?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, moq, async-await

Let's say I have some APM (BeginXxx, EndXxx) pattern async methods (as part of some WCF service proxy i'm calling):

```
public interface ISomeService
{
    IAsyncResult BeginSomeMethod(int num, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    int EndSomeMethod(IAsyncResult ar);
}
```

My actual code uses uses the `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to create a Task, and then awaiting this task using the new async/await pattern introduced in .net 4.5.

I would like to test my class and thus I need to write a method that receives the mock, begin method, end method and return value and sets up the mock so that it would eventually return the required return value.

example usage:

```
SetupAsync(mock, mocked => mocked.BeginSomeMethod, mocked=> mocked.EndSomeMethod, 7);
```

Which will cause an async flow with any int argument to return 7.
I  cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish such a thing in moq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I recommend that you use the `TaskWsdlImportExtension` to create `Task`-based asynchronous WCF proxies. VS2012 does this by default, but you [have to set it up yourself](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/async/thread/47994f10-da43-4c7b-9756-6432a6188d98#4710c459-43e1-4705-8692-f0b5d1106881) on VS2010+AsyncCTP. It's easier to unit test against a `Task` API.

If you do want to unit test against `Begin`/`End`, I think the easiest way would be to use `Task`-based mocks and expose `Begin`/`End` endpoints. The `[AsyncFactory|AsyncFactory<T>].[ToBegin|ToEnd]` methods in my [AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) library provide `Begin`/`End` method wrappers around a `Task`, or you can see [Stephen Toub's blog post about writing these kinds of wrappers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/06/27/10179452.aspx).

You can get simple already-completed tasks from `Task.FromResult`, or you can use the following construct to force an asynchronously-completed task:

```
Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Yield(); return 7; });
```

(the Async CTP equivalent would be):

```
TaskEx.RunEx(async () => { await TaskEx.Yield(); return 7; });
```

I'm not entirely sure how to tie this into Moq. Again, I suspect a `Task`-based API would be easier to mock than `Begin`/`End`. `Begin`/`End` has its own special semantics (you have to pass the correct `IAsyncResult`, `End` must be called exactly once for each `Begin`, etc), so there's more stuff to test.